# Why is access to Windows shares (SMB) slow from Emacs for Windows (x86-64)?

Tags: microsoft-windows

I use Emacs at work for most things, on Windows, and things are mostly good (slow Magit notwithstanding). But one thing completely puzzles me: opening files or directories on Windows shares (SMB) takes multiple seconds. This isn't true for the same files on other applications, like Windows Explorer or VS Code. This is native Emacs, not Cygwin or WSL. I'm not trying to use Tramp to access them, just the path to the share.

Any ideas?